# symfony 5 get data of many to many relation

Tags: symfony

how i  get user_id of table : **user_evento** ?

i need compare who user join on table : **evento**,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6PcO.png)

**controller**

```
    public function evento_detalle(Evento $evento){
        if(!$evento){
          return $this->redirectToRout('ver_eventos');
        } 
        $salas = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Sala::class)->findBy([],['id' => 'desc']);
        $users =  $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class) ->findBy([],['id' => 'ASC']);

        return $this->render('evento/ver-evento.html.twig',[
            'eventos' =>$evento,
            'users' =>$users,
            'salas' =>$salas
        ]);

    }
```

**twig**

```
{% for user in users %}
    {% if user.id == eventos.getUsers.evento %}
    <tr>
        <td>

        {{ user.nombre }} 

        </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>  </td>

    </tr>
    {%endif%}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're asking for. The code is comparing the user's id, with events for that user-id, owned by the same user. Which seem to be doubling. Why not just iterating over the user's eventos? I suppose you're using Doctrine. Could you please share your M2M relationship between user/eventos?

Comment: i cant compare who user join on the table. On relation many to many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to list `Users` associated with a particular `Evento` you should find them all in the collection returned by the `Evento::getUsers()` method, provided you have followed best practices for Symfony.

```
{% for user in eventos.getUsers %}
  ...
  {{ user.nombre }} 
  ...
{% endfor %}
```